# Setting up custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, custom-attributes

I'm trying to display an additional product attribute when managing a product's attributes.

I've set up the attribute as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMSa7.jpg

the descriptions (addable and editable by admin users in the config section) need to be displayed as a multi select dropdown.

I've written the following to programmatically add the attribute for products:

```
<?php
/* @var $this Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'additional_product_description', array(
    'group'                => 'General',
    'type'              => 'text',
    'backend'           => 'adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array', // ***** NOT SURE IF THIS IS CORRECT, PLEASE ADVISE *****
    'frontend_input'    => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Additional Product Descriptions',
    'input'             => 'multiselect',
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => '***** ***** ***** NEED HELP HERE ***** ***** *****',
    'global'             => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,//can be SCOPE_WEBSITE or SCOPE_STORE
    'visible'           => true,
    'used_in_product_listing' =>true, //can also be false
    'frontend_class'     => '',
    'required'          => false,//can be true
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'searchable'        => false,//can be true
    'filterable'        => false,//can be true
    'comparable'        => false,//can be true
    'visible_on_front'  => false,//can be true
    'unique'            => false,
    'position'            => 60,//put any number here
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

I can't figure out what I am supposed to use as the source - could anyone please advise?

The system.xml that sets up the serialized array I want to use for the attribute is the following:

```
<fields>
    <descriptions translate="label">
        <label>Product Descriptions</label>
        <frontend_model>runwaysale_productdescription/adminhtml_descriptions</frontend_model>
        <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array</backend_model>
        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    </descriptions>
</fields>
```

I have already tested, and the config section works without any issues, I now need to add an attribute field to the products' attributes.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25597/how-to-create-multi-select-attribute-for-customer-using-install-script