# How to add multiselect attribute to customer registration form?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-attribute

I want to add an attribute to admin registration form and to allow users to select multiple values. I can add a simple text field to the form but need help on how to add multi-select drop-down or check-boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25597/how-to-create-multi-select-attribute-for-customer-using-install-script)  for creating multi-select attribute for customer in magento. I hope this will help you.