# Magento 1.9 / OpenMage: Adding a static attribute to the customer table and forms that is a physical coumn in the customer_entity table

Tags: magento-1.9, openmage

After reading [this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25597/how-to-create-multi-select-attribute-for-customer-using-install-script) that is sort of what we need to achieve (and does it with a custom attribute), it's not quite what I need and so I thought it would be good to ask the experts here.

We have a table, let's call it "customer_segment" with the following basic structure:

```
customer_segment_id
name
```

Then we've added a foreign key to the `customer_entity` table `customer_segment_id` that references the `customer_segment_id` in the `customer_segment` table.

Instead of hacking/overriding classes to get this field into the customer form, it seems logical that we can create a "static" attribute almost exactly like the customer `group_id` as it would also need to be attributed to orders, again just like `group_id`.

There are some hints in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175307/magento-adding-static-attribute-to-catalog-product-but-cant-ensure-saving-val) and the author appears to do a similar thing with the order entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the column like this:

```php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$table = $installer->getTable('customer/entity');
$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($table, 'segment_id', [
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => true,
        'comment'   => 'Segment ID'
    ]);
$installer->getConnection()->addConstraint('FK_CUST_ENTITY_SEGMENT_ID',
    $table, 'segment_id',
    'customer_segment', 'customer_segment_id',
    'set null'
);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Then you can add the static attribute like this:

```php
Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->setData([
    'entity_type_id' => 1,
    'attribute_code' => 'segment_id',
    'backend_type' => 'static',
    'frontend_input' => 'text',
    'frontend_Label' => 'Segment ID',
    'is_user_defined' => 1,
    'is_visible' => 1,
    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create', 'checkout_register'] // Remove what you do not need
])
->save();
```